# JS Fetch API access return value

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

This is how I access the result from a fetch call:

```
let data;

fetch(someUri)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(_data => {
        data = _data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Is it also possible to access the result from the fetch function itself, like this:

```
let data = fetch(someUri)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // do some stuff
        return data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        return error;
    });
```

So `data` will be either the JSON data or the error. I see in my Chrome console that the result is in the variable, but I don't know how to access it because it's wrapped with other information.

Comment: No because `fetch` returns a promise. The data is being fetched asynchronously.

Comment: No, you can't do that.  It runs asynchronously.  You need to use promises accordingly.

Comment: How can I handle promises, you got an example link?

Comment: There are a *lot* of resources online for using JS promises.  Use Google.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can wrap it inside an immediately invoked async function and use await:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/ok72rfp6/

```
!async function(){
let data = await fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IbrahimTanyalcin/LEXICON/master/lexiconLogo.png")
    .then((response) => response.blob())
    .then(data => {
        return data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });

console.log(data);
}();
```

Comment: Thank you. => response.json() would be useful to many. Currently you proceed even if there's no data, the example might be improved with a check or better yet, replacing return data; with code to process the data on success. Why !async? It's not required.

Comment: Can `data` be accessed outside async function?

Comment: @Dounchan ,  `return` from the async: `const mydata = (async function(){... return data})()`

Answer (score 7):

Here are some good resources for fetch and an example.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json

You may also want to get familiar with promises.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

```js
 
    function doSomethingWithText(text) {
        console.log('The text is:', text);
    }

    fetch('someUrl.html')
      .then(data => data.text())
      .then(doSomethingWithText)
      .catch(error => new Error(error));
```

Answer (score 1):

fetch method returns a promise that resolves to a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object.

Once you get the response, it is up to you what to do with it. You can use methods on response body like json, text or blob to get data into desired format to work with.