# json response from API replace with dummy data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to follow some tutorial on youtube, and trying to build an admin dashboard
the tutorial uses some dummy data for the portal

```
export const ordersData = [
   {
     OrderID: 10248,
     CustomerName: 'Vinet',
   },
   {
     OrderID: 345653,
     CustomerName: 'Carson Darrin',
   }, etc...
```

i try to replicate with the real API interaction

```
export const ordersData = fetch('API_URL', {method:"GET"})
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    }).then(data => {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data.body))
      return JSON.parse(data.body)
    })
```

but its seems not to work as expected, i try to compare the console.log with the directly input data
they look the same in the console, both of them are shown as objects (typeof).

not sure which step is going wrong

Comment: `its seems not to work as expected` - what exactly is wrong? Maybe back-end is returning wrong data/headers?

Comment: can you show as the result of "console.log(data)

Comment: One thing can be that static content is returned directly and in your `fetch` example your `ordersData` is promise

Comment: why not just do a log as - `console.log(data)` and go from there ... :)

Comment: The table cant show the data from api, console.log are showing the same result as the dummy

Comment: can you show the table component which is using the data?

Comment: Are you parsing json multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here you want to `return` from `fetch` browser API, which returns `Promise`. If you really want to do it, for instance, instead of using `useState` hook in React to call and save the response in component state, then you need to wrap your `fetch` request into `async` [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) function and use `await` statement to wait the async request to be fulfilled and the data to be resolved by `Promise`. For more info, you can refer: [JS Fetch API access return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50417982/js-fetch-api-access-return-value)

Answer (score 1):

write your fetch in an useEffect and set its response in a state

```
const [data, setData] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
fetch('API_URL', {method:"GET"})
    .then(res => {
      return JSON.parse(res);
    }).then(response => {
      setData(response)
    })
}, [])
```